# I just wanted to know what reduce method actaully does? 'it converts the array to single value' means what?

Tags: arrays

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});

Answer (score 1):

1. initializes **previousValue** as array[0]
2. initializes **currentIndex** as 1
3. It loops through array's elements from **currentIndex**, and saves functions result to **previousValue**
4. returns **previousValue**

```js
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(
    function (previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
        console.info(arguments);
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    });
```